# How to reduce DB query/call in MongoDB when query need more than one collection to authenticate user and send data that user is requested?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, jwt

I am using MongoDB with node js and express. I wanna store the user data and it's all plans in MongoDB. As we know MongoDB doesn't support joins, so we've left 2 choices either use **population** or **subdocuments**. So not to make it complex I've created a new collection named **plans** and use population. But every time I want to query data from the plan, I've to authenticate the user and then provide the data. so for every request to get data from plan collection:

1. I've to send a query to authenticate use using JWT and check if user is authentic.
2. Then again query from plan data and send the response.

So Is there any way we can authenticate users and send data in one DB query.
Thanks in advance

Comment: why dont you embedd the plans inside the users document?

Comment: Plans size could be large and to make it simple I thought it would be easy if I separate them in 2 different documents. Please correct me If I'm wrong.

Comment: Use aggregation pipeline.

Comment: @D.SM I don't understang what is the use of aggreagation pipeline here. Could you elaborate please ?

Comment: To retrieve data from multiple collections, you would use aggregation pipeline. If you don't know how it works it has extensive documentation.

Comment: Use the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage to left join other collection based on criteria